# VBA script or excel formula to add data in a worksheet from another workbook, based on a set of rules

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make a macro that copies data from a CentralData workbook into another workbook, based on a set of conditions.

Below you'll find the general format of both files:

[image: Synth file]
[image: CentralData]

1st picture is the simulation of the synth file where i want data from the other to be pasted. Date column represents  generic dates with the format 'mm/dd/yy'. Central data is the second file from where i want the data to be extracted. The numbers in the cells are just a simulation with generic numbers, in order to see how it needs to be filled.

The bankdata is a separate file that doesn't have a part in the problem, but helps visualize the format of the synth file. Delta is the difference between CentralData and synth. That cell and bankdata needs to be skipped.

The second file, CentralData, contains the filename from which the data is extracted. The file names, although it seems random, are a combinatins of standard string (sometimes separated by a symbol), the file date (date format 'ddmmyy') and '.fileextension'.

The objective is, according to the common date from both table, in the CentralData line from synth, to paste each value from CentralData, that match the method. (think payment method) for every line in the synth and every line in CentralData file, until everything in populated in the synth.

First, i tried with functions like =IF(AND($B2="CentralData";'[centralData.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B2="method2");'[centralData.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C2;" ") for each method, or to create some kind of token system to match the date from synth with the date from CentralData. In the end, it failed, or works for some data.

Now, i'm trying to make a macro that copies sums from central data to synth, based on date, method, and column, and, by now i have this:

```vb
Sub FillData()
'will get data from CentralData and paste it into synth, according to a set of conditions
'
'
'
Dim x As Integer                    'will store sums
Dim wb, wbsec As Workbook           'wb-primary workbook (synth) wbsec-secondary workbook hat will do all the operations
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mainstr, workingstr As String   'mainstr will store the date conversion and workingstr will store conditions and other string type variables

'Workbooks.Open ("") 
'Set ws = Sheet1                     

'split the text in the first column and store only the numeric value
Dim newr As Variant
Range("b:b").Insert
Dim newr As Range
newr = Range("A2")
Dim i As Integer


'convert left number into date format
Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "mmddyy"


End Sub

Public Function SplitText(pWorkRng As Range, pIsNumber As Boolean) As String

Dim xLen As Long
Dim xStr As String
xLen = VBA.Len(pWorkRng.Value)
For i = 1 To xLen
    xStr = VBA.Mid(pWorkRng.Value, i, 1)
    If ((VBA.IsNumeric(xStr) And pIsNumber) Or (Not (VBA.IsNumeric(xStr)) And Not (pIsNumber))) Then
        SplitText = SplitText + xStr
    End If
Next

End Function
```

Now, i need to convert the short date from filename to an actual date (kinda done) and to compare with the date from synth, then, i'll write the other conditions. Is this the best approach? How should i proceed from here? Are there more things i need to provide?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot understand which is the ID column (unique keys) to match the two sheets? Which of the two picture is the one to extract data (I suppose the second one) and based on what to be distributed on the first one?

Comment: There isn't an ID key. The sheets needs to be matched by methods, sums, and dates. The data needs to be extracted from the sheet that contains the filenames. Should i create a new column to add some IDs? @FaneDuru

Comment: I am afraid I still cannot understand what you try accomplishing. A normal/good question should explain **in words** what you try doing. I cannot understand what the first picture represents. Was it initially empty and it became what we can see after processing of the second one? If so, what `date1` should mean? Should we understand that there should be brought the date extracted from the file names? If so, why only `date1`, since there will be three different date? Then, supposing that this is  what you try doing, what does `centralData`, `bankData` and `delta` mean?

Comment: Besides all that, I am afraid that the numeric part of the file names may be inconsistent. You do not say in which format the numeric representation can be understood. It looks to be `dmmyy`. Since one time the date is represented in 5 digits and other times 6 digits, it can be processed if being sure that **always** the month is represented in two digits, but your example it is not good, not showing the cases of two digits months. If it is possible to also contain one digit, it will not be possible to determine a number like `11121`. Should it be eleventh of January or first of November?

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of explanations given. I tried to be as concise as possible, without bore anyone with a wall of text that explains everything i want to do. I'll edit the question to fill in with more details.

Comment: Still not clear enough, in order to supply an answer. So, you confused us with the numeric part you used. They have to be date in format "ddmmyy". Then, an extension should also be contained. Now, I could not understand the rest of your explanation. If the code will start form 'centralData', what to be filled instead of the 'CentralData' in your picture? The workbook/sheet name? Only mentioning the file names, how to "match the method. (think payment method) for every line"? Should all the files exist in the same folder? If so, you should provide its path, at least.

Comment: Then, What "populated in the synth" should mean? If you are not able to speak in terms of ranges, nobody can understand something existing only in your head, I am afraid...

Comment: As it stands right now, i'm pretty bad at giving details. I guess these 2 workbooks need to be in the same folder to work, or the code should run from the synth file and prompt the user to input the path to the CentralData. Also, populating the table is refering to the operation of inserting data (in this case, copy from CentralData and pasting in synth). For now, i'll paste the code for getting the numberic part out, in a separate column, and then, converting it into a "date" type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to transform the file name numeric part in `Date`, please try using the next function. It assumes that the month inside the numeric string is **always** composed from two digits, except the case when both (day and month) are composed from only one digit. If the numeric part is not consistent and it may contain also months of one digit and day of two digits, nobody can extract a real `Date` from such a bad construction:

```
Function extractDt(fileName As String) As Date
   Dim strNum As String, Dt As Date
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "(\d{4,6})" 'number digits, from 4 to 6
        .Global = True
        If .test(fileName) Then
            strNum = CStr(.Execute(fileName)(0))
        End If
    End With
    If Len(strNum) = 6 Then
        Dt = DateSerial(20 & CLng(Right(strNum, 2)), CLng(Mid(strNum, 3, 2)), CLng(left(strNum, 2)))
   ElseIf Len(strNum) = 5 Then
        Dt = DateSerial(20 & CLng(Right(strNum, 2)), CLng(Mid(strNum, 2, 2)), CLng(left(strNum, 1)))
   ElseIf Len(strNum) = 4 Then
        Dt = DateSerial(20 & CLng(Right(strNum, 2)), CLng(Mid(strNum, 2, 1)), CLng(left(strNum, 1)))
   End If
   extractDt = Dt
End Function
```

It can be tested using the next way:

```
Sub testExgtractNumb()
   Dim strNum As String
   Debug.Print extractDt("filename011121")
   'Debug.Print extractDt("filename11121")
   'Debug.Print extractDt("filename1721")
End Sub
```

Please, uncomment the lines with different numeric representation of `Date` and see the result in `Immediate Window`.

If you will answer my clarification questions, I will try a global response. Now I cannot understand what you mean. Your question is  not to clear from the mentioned aspects, point of view...